# Logical paradox in python?

Tags: python

I came over this, where "not None" equals both True and False simultaneously.

```
>>> not None
True

>>> not None == True
True

>>> not None == False
True
```

At first I expected that this would be because of the order of operators, but however when testing a similar expression:

```
>>> not False
True

>>> not False == False
False

>>> not False == True
True
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: I found [this page](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary) very useful

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This *is* due to operator precedence. `not none == True` means `not (None == True)` means `None != True`, which is true. Similarly, `None != False` is also true. The value `None` is distinct from the booleans.

Your last two expressions mean `False != False`, which is false, and `False != True`, which is true.

Comment: @Dog eat cat world: yes. But then, keep in mind that `(not None) == True` is true, while `(not True) == None` is false, since `None != False`. To convert a value that may be `None` to a boolean, call `bool` on it.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed due to operator precedence.  `not None == False` will be evaluated as `not (None == False)`.  `None == False` is `False`, which explains your results.

Try this instead:

```
>>> (not None) == True
True
>>> (not None) == False
False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> not None
True
>>> not None == True
True
>>> not None == False
True
>>> (not None) == True
True
>>> (not None) == False
False
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the order of expansion. python reads them like this

```
o>>> not (None == True)
True
>>> not (None == False)
True
>>> not False
True
>>> not (False == False)
False
>>> not (False == True)
True
>>>
```

I think this makes it clear.